# Linq to SQL one to many relationships

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

Last couple of days i was struggling with a linq querys performance:

```
LinqConnectionDataContext context = new LinqConnectionDataContext();
System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions options = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Question>(x => x.Answers);
options.LoadWith<Question>(x => x.QuestionVotes);
options.LoadWith<Answer>(x => x.AnswerVotes);
context.LoadOptions = options;
var query =( from c in context.Questions
            where c.UidUser == userGuid
            && c.Answers.Any() == true
            select new
            {
                c.Uid,
                c.Content,
                c.UidUser,
                QuestionVote = from qv in c.QuestionVotes where qv.UidQuestion == c.Uid && qv.UidUser == userGuid select new {qv.UidQuestion, qv.UidUser },
                Answer = from d in c.Answers
                         where d.UidQuestion == c.Uid
                         select new
                         {
                             d.Uid,
                             d.UidUser,
                             d.Conetent,
                             AnswerVote = from av in d.AnswerVotes where av.UidAnswer == d.Uid && av.UidUser == userGuid select new { av.UidAnswer, av.UidUser }
                         }
            }).ToList();
```

Query have to run through 5000 rows, and it takes up to 1 minute. How can i improve performance of this query?

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: stored procedures? Indexes on the columns you are using for JOIN and WHERE clause on SQL side?

Comment: Update my question with tables picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something to get you started.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetQuestionsAndAnswers
(
    @UserGuid VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
c.Uid, 
c.Content, 
c.UidUser, 
qv.UidQuestion, 
qv.UidUser, 
av.UidAnswer, 
av.UidUser, 
av.Content,
d.Uid,
d.UidUser,
d.Content
FROM Question c
INNER JOIN QuestionVotes qv ON qv.UidQuestion = c.Uid AND qv.UidUser = @UserGuid
INNER JOIN Answers d ON d.UidQuestion = c.Uid
INNER JOIN AnswerVotes av ON av.UidAnswer = d.Uid AND av.UidUser = @UserGuid
WHERE c.UidUser = @UserGuid

END
```

You will already have clustered indexes on primary columns by default (just confirm this on your database side), and you would want non-clustered indexes on QuestionVote - UidUser column, AnswerVote - UidUser column, and Answer - UidQuestion column.

Also have a look here. You might want to use `.AsQueryable()` instead of `ToList()` for deferred execution

[Do you ToList()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334579/do-you-tolist)

Comment: oh.. snap... problem with this stored precidure is that it creates inner join, but what i have is : Question and QuestionVotes have one to many realtionship, same with Answer and AnswerVote

Comment: then you can use the group by clause on question.uid, answer.uid

Answer (score 1):

Checked out the generated sql using [sql-debug-visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx)  and then copy the generated SQL and run it from SQL Client and see how much time it takes. If it takes near to 1 min you need to imporve performance at DB Level by adding indexing and / or stored procedure or creating views etc.

If above is not taking much time you can always create [Stored Procedure and call that using LINQ to SQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/328009/Use-stored-procedure-with-linq-to-sql)L.

One more recommendation is to use Entity Framework [if you can change to because](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123569/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql) it is the future.