# difference of a parsed context (.toList()) and not parsed context

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC. Now, I've searched in the internet what does the `.toList()` do.

> Using ToList() method to force LINQ query execute immediately
>
> calling ToList() method, you force LINQ to execute immediately and
>   return actual results.

But what's the difference between these two.

`return View(db.Items)` and `return View(db.Items.ToList())`

Because I can still see the same result in my page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `View(db.Items.ToList())` statement first execute `ToList()` method and get result from database and pass to the view.

and `View(db.Items)` first call view with LINQ query and view will call ToList method to get list from database (late binding).

Comment: So which is more preferred? So you mean, once you pass results to the view whether its parse or not, it will execute `.ToList()`?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work But basically forcing the query to execute immediately by using `ToList()` you may lose some of the benefits of deferred execution (by not using `ToList()`) and possibly some other benefits. But check out the post, it may help. Also, you may not want to hold all objects in memory first then work with them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334579/do-you-tolist